# Creating a RestRequest for Twitter using OAuth1.0

Tags: c#, oauth, twitter, restsharp

I'm trying to create a valid RestRequest for taking advantage of the [GET statuses/user_timeline.json](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) provided by the Twitter API.

I have a dev account and my Consumer Key/Secret and AccessToken/TokenSecret

```
_restClient.Timeout = 60000;
_restClient.BaseUrl = "http://api.twitter.com/1.1"

_restClient.Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(cKey, cSecret, aT, aTSecret)

var request = new RestRequest("statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=default", Method.GET)

var response = _restClient.Execute(request)
```

To this request I receive the response

> {"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}

I suspect that I'm missing a step, since many resources I've found reach out to the BaseUrl of "api.twitter.com" first in order to make an TokenRequest, but I already have my token, so I'm not sure why that step would be necessary.

Thanks!

**SOLUTION:**

I've solved the problem simply by using the c# package TweetSharp

```
var service = new TwitterService(_twitterConfiguration.ConsumerKey, _twitterConfiguration.ConsumerSecret);
service.AuthenticateWith(_twitterConfiguration.AccessToken, _twitterConfiguration.AccessTokenSecret);
```

The above is everything you need to get connected to the twitter-api-1.1 service (as well as you're relevant tokens)

Comment: Great you found a solution! You are actually allowed (and encouraged) to answer your own question. That helps signal more clearly that your issue has been solved. Can you move your solution into an answer? Thanks!